# Como establezco un array como parametro en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, array, mongodb, reactjs

he estado intentando una nueva función a mi programa, este programa tiene como finalidad hacer mas facil la busqueda de elementos dentro de un array, todos estos elementos son unicos, una forma de buscarlos y entregarlos es mediante un rank, dandole dos parametros en el endpoint (inicio y final) cuando el usuario establece el valor de inicio y el de final, el programa retorna los valores entre estos dos, perfecto. Pero también tiene otra opción donde el usuario puede especificar solo algunos elementos del array y así solo mostrar estos en el programa...

Answer (score 1):

No entendí del todo tu pregunta, pero lo que logré captar fue que necesitas una función que te permita buscar un valor detro de un arreglo, o una subsección de ese arreglo, puedes utilizar find y slice.

```
var frutas = ['fresa', 'manzana', 'banana'];
var fresa = frutas.find(fruta => fruta === 'fresa');
var manzanaBanana = frutas.splice(1,2);
var banana = manzanaBanana.find(fruta => fruta === 'banana');
//Y para mostrar solo algunos elementos podrías utilizar la función filter
var fresaBanana = ['fresa', 'banana'];
var frutasVIP = frutas.filter(fruta => fresaBanana.indexOf(fruta) > -1);
```

Comment: Gracias MauCano, puedo ver lo que haces ahí, mi problema es que el usuario es quien debe establecer los elementos especificos que se extraeran del array original y para esto debo tener en cuenta que tengo solo dos parametros (inicio y final) en el que el usuario puede establecer un rango de elementos del array entre esos dos numeros impuestos en (inicio y final) pienso que debe hacerse un If statement para que tome un parametro especial cuando no quiera buscar un rango de elementos sino, una busqueda especifica de elementos unicos dentro del mismo array. Gracias, creo que con filter va la cosa

Comment: No deberías de usar un parámetro como pivot para saber si la búsqueda es por rango, mejor deberías hacer funciones especializadas.

Una que busque general y otra que reciba el arreglo, inicio y fin.

Algo así:  var findIn = function(criterio, arrelgo) {///implementación}

var findInWithIndex = function(criterio, arreglo, start, end) {//implementación}


Pudiera parecer más talacha pero al final ayudará a que tu código sea más mantenible.